# IF statement in MySQL using @var

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement

I have this code in MySQL

```
SELECT @v_new := IF( 
IFNULL(tpud_credit,0)+
IFNULL(tpud_value_cash,0) > 0, 1, 0) AS v_new
FROM trs_transaction_detail
WHERE tpud_pk = '1116801472ATR4019550';


IF (@v_new = 1) THEN SELECT @v_new; END IF;
```

When "SELECT @v_new" im placed after WHERE and not using IF, it can be to run. A problem why im got error when using that IF statement? something wrong?

Comment: Is this code running in a stored program (procedure,trigger,function, event)? 'MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-statements.html

Comment: No, just normal querying. Just it query is  I want to running.

Comment: constructs for flow control are only supported within stored programs